# send_mail() not sending to email to associated email address

Tags: python, sendmail

I'm trying to send a personalised email to each email address in the list. The print statement shows that the message is being composed correctly. The problem is that instead of multiple emails, I get the same email multiple times. I'm using a filebased emailbackend. This is my code

````
def send_lst():
    for row in df.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
        name = getattr(row, "full_name")
        email = getattr(row, "email_address")
        action = getattr(row, "action")
        device = getattr(row, "device_name")
        barcode = getattr(row, "barcode")
        instance = getattr(row, "instanceID")
        emailed = getattr(row, "emailed")
        date = getattr(row, "receipt_date")

        message = 'Dear {}, \nYou have been recorded as {} a {} with barcode {} on {}. \nIf this information is incorrect, please contact the Digital Team.'.format(name, action, device, barcode, date)
        send_mail('Asset tracker confirmation',
                  message,
                  'me@company.org',
                  [email],
                  fail_silently=False)
        return ()

    print(message)```
````

Comment: You will hit `return` on the first iteration which will end the execution of the function. And actually like this you should never get any printout.

Comment: So are you saying I should remove the return to solve the problem? I'm a newbie, why do you say I should'nt get any printout?

Comment: If there is at least one iteration the `return` will be reached before the `print`. If there isn't any iteration `message` will the undefined resulting in a `NameError`.

Comment: Removing the return worked. Thanx Klaus!